# Ember.Select blank on page load, but first option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, ember.js, ember.select

I have an Ember.Select select box (because nowhere on the interwebs had details on grabbing a value from a regular old select box from the controller--bonus points if you can enlighten be about that) that works *almost* perfectly. The problem is, on page load, it shows up blank. Completely blank:
[image]

However, if I click it, you'll see the right default value is selected:

[image]

There isn't even an empty option. If I escape it, it stays blank, but as soon as I click on an option:
[image]

So here's my controller, where it's grabbing its options from:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
selectedDistance: null,
selectDistance: [
    { label: "within 10 mi", value: "10" },
    { label: "within 20 mi", value: "20" },
    { label: "within 5000 mi", value: "5000" },
],
});
```

Here's the snippet that creates the Ember.Select:

```
{{view Ember.Select
content=selectDistance  
optionValuePath="content.value" 
optionLabelPath="content.label"
selectionBinding="selectedDistance"}}
```

Here's the rendered HTML:

```
<select id="ember458" class="ember-view ember-select form-control">
    <script id="metamorph-3-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-3-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-4-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-8-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-5-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <option id="ember478" class="ember-view" value="10">
        <script id="metamorph-9-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
        within 10 mi
        <script id="metamorph-9-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    </option>
    <script id="metamorph-5-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-6-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <option id="ember479" class="ember-view" value="20">
        <script id="metamorph-10-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
        within 20 mi
        <script id="metamorph-10-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    </option>
    <script id="metamorph-6-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-7-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <option id="ember480" class="ember-view" value="5000">
        <script id="metamorph-11-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
        within 5000 mi
        <script id="metamorph-11-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    </option>
    <script id="metamorph-7-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-8-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-4-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</select>
```

Grabbing values works fine and the form works fine, but how do I stop it from being blank initially? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a `prompt` property to `Ember.Select`. This will add a default `<option>` to the rendered `<select>` with no value. This option will be displayed when there is no `selection`:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  content=selectDistance  
  optionValuePath="content.value" 
  optionLabelPath="content.label"
  selectionBinding="selectedDistance"
  prompt="Please Select"}}
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#toc_supplying-a-prompt